# ¿Cómo saco un campo de un elemento de una lista a partir de otro campo del mismo elemento? (Flutter)

Tags: lista, flutter, dart

En Flutter, tengo una lista con varias instancias del modelo "Usuario". Cada instancia tiene los campos "email" y "tipoDeCuenta". Quiero saber cómo sacar el tipoDeCuenta de la instancia con el email "test@test.com".

Comment: Hola bienvenido, podrías mirar [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Que has intentado?  podrías colocar el error que te manda e incluido el código que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

La forma de básica con for imagino que es una opción si la lista no es muy grande:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if(list[i].email == "test@test.com"){
        print(list[i].tipoDeCuenta); //La encontre
        break; //Si hay una sola y para no seguir buscando
      }
}
```